# wordpress nginx redirect folder

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx, nginx-location

nice people! :)

I have migrated a website (WordPress site) to another server.
The wordpress install originally was in domain.com/site/, and it had an index file that redirected users to /site/.
Now the WP install is in the root folder (domain.com/).
I need to make that every request to domain.com/site/?p=x go to domain.com/?p=x
I have been looking all over trying a lot of location rules, but I cant make it work. The best I could do is redirect from domain.com/site/?p=x to domain.com/site?p=x, and obviously that gives an 404.
The server in which the website was, was apache. Now in the new server I use nginx.
I have used easyengine to install nginx, php-fpm, mysql. Created a wordpress site with w3tc plugin.

Can somebody help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question!

[Nginx](http://ports.su/www/nginx) is a good choice, do this in your `nginx.conf`:

```
location /site {
    rewrite ^/site/?((?<=/).*)?$    /$1 redirect;
    return  403;
}
```

The `(?<=` part is a *lookbehind assertion*, as per [`pcrepattern(3)`](http://mdoc.su/n/pcrepattern.3), which is from the [`pcre`](http://ports.su/devel/pcre) library that both [Apache `httpd`](http://ports.su/www/apache-httpd) as well as [`nginx`](http://ports.su/www/nginx) use in support of the regular expressions.

The `return 403;` is necessary in case there is a security issue with the regular expression as written (e.g., if it fails to provide a redirect).